# Time series clustering visualization on ggplot2- different cluster colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have applied Hierarchical clustering to the following dataset using dynamic time warping. When I plot the graph using ggplot2 I would like the different clusters to have different colours instead of different colours for each time series (currently shown in Figure 1: Vehicle clusters). Figure 2 is the result I get when trying to achieve this. It seems to colour the clusters correctly but fills in between which I don't want. My suspicion is that it is to do with the group_by functions and when I attempt to use the mutate function.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

For completeness, I have included the raw dataset and program. Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
library(fpc)
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dtw)
library(gghighlight)

#Importing data
df <- read_csv("01_tracks.csv")

#Preparing data 
df1 <- filter(df,laneId == 2, width <= 6) #Filtering to only lane 3 and no trucks
#df1$id <- as.numeric(df1$id)
df1$xVelocity <- abs(df1$xVelocity)

#Creates a Data Frame of just the x-Velocity
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
  dplyr::select(time, xVelocity) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = time, values_from = xVelocity,
              names_from = id) %>%
  select(-time) %>%
  t()

 tdf <- df2[1:10,] #Only using first 10 vehicles to make computing time quick for convience in tests

xy.list <- setNames(split(tdf, seq(nrow(tdf))), rownames(tdf)) #Turn the data frame into a list
new.list <- lapply(xy.list, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]) #Take out all the NA values in the list

#Hierarchial Clustering
distance.matrix <- dist(new.list, method= "DTW") #Create a distance Matrix
hc <- hclust(distance.matrix, method= "average") #Performing hierarchical clustering

#Processing cluster groups
Number_of_clusters <- 3
clustered_data <- cutree(hc, k = Number_of_clusters)
clustered_data_tidy <- as.data.frame(as.table(clustered_data)) %>% glimpse()
colnames(clustered_data_tidy) <- c("id","cluster")
clustered_data_tidy$id <- as.character(clustered_data_tidy$id)
clustered_data_tidy$id <- as.numeric(clustered_data_tidy$id)

#Making a data frame with the cluster group
joined_clusters <- df1 %>% inner_join(clustered_data_tidy, by = "id") %>% glimpse()

  pl2 <- joined_clusters %>% #replace pl3 with joined_clusters
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time = 1:n()) %>% #Creating time variable for the x-axis
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = xVelocity)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = cluster), show.legend = FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste("Vehicle clusters"))
  print(gpl2 <- ggplotly(pl2))
```

Comment: Instead of posting all your data-preprocessing code + link to the full dataset, can you include the output from `dput(joined_clusters)` in your question? If you are asking about ggplot2, the earlier parts are not really relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are telling ggplot that you want just three lines with three different colours, but you want ten lines with three different colours.

In your ggplot call, you are passing only three variables to be mapped to aesthetics: the x co-ordinate, the y co-ordinate and the colour. You have not told ggplot that the x and y co-ordinates within each color should be separated into different lines, so it just joins them all up within each color group.

To fix this, you need to add the vehicle id as a `group` aesthetic to specify that you still want the x and y co-ordinates from each line to be plotted separately:

```r
  joined_clusters %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(time = 1:n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = time, y = xVelocity)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = factor(cluster), group = id), 
              size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
    ggtitle(paste("Vehicle clusters"))
```

[image]